# How to use functions in .so file in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I've extracted `.so` file from apk which I didn't write and added it as library in my android studio project.
I declared class name same with `.so` file however studio can't resolve the name of native method. How can I figure out native method's prototype only with `.so` file?

Answer (score 1):

You can list all the symbols in `.so` file and find the exported JNI calls. If the JNI methods are not registered in `JNI_Onload`, they are usually prefixed with `Java_com_xxx`. So you can get all the symbols name by following command. Suppose you have installed NDK in your development environment.

```
$ arm-linux-androideabi-readelf -s libtest.so  |arm-linux-androideabi-c++filt |grep Java
```

Comment: Thank you! I got a name of function. : `Java_kr_co_lab_interc`   So I  created native method named `interc` in package named `kr.co` and class named `lab` but studio still can't resolve. Can you please give me a hint?

Comment: `.so` file is in libs folder of project as `.jar` extension

Comment: Did you load the library in class lab by calling `System.loadLibrary("");`

Comment: I did `System.loadLibray("SO_file_name")`

Comment: your `.so` should be in a folder `/app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7` with `.so` extension